# Format figure headers in Word created with R-Markdown and

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a R-markdown document in Word format and have gotten most stuff to work as i want but having trouble with my figure headers.

I want to format my figure headers but unfortunately I cant get a title on it to format. I have a template.docx-file with all my formats but that doesn't help me when my figure-header ends up with the Normal style (which needs to be as-is for normal text).

Judging by examples on here this should be possible. **I'm using the captioner-package**

Reproducible example code here except template-file

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Some_author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(captioner)
fig_nums <- captioner()

```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

`r fig_nums("Press_plot", "Great figure header")`

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand this doesn't seem to work in vanilla R-Markdown but with the package officedown I finally got it to work.

```
install.packages("officedown")
library(officedown)
```

On top of that I created in my reference document two styles named Figure and Caption (officedown gave a warning when they didn't exist) with the desired formatting. Working code as this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Some_author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: Template.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(captioner)
fig_nums <- captioner()

```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:


```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="economics plot", fig.id = "tsplot", fig.cap.style = "Caption", fig.topcaption=TRUE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````